# actionscript little error

Tags: xml, flash, actionscript, slider, slideshow

hello i have written these piece of code, when i run PUBLISH it shows me no error but when i run flash window on last poster it shows

```
TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.
    at slider_fla::MainTimeline/nextClick()
```

here code:

```
    var sliderNum:int = 0;
    var sliderMaxNum:int = 0;

function nextClick(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    if (sliderNum > sliderMaxNum){
        sliderNum = 0;
    }
    var myTween:Tween = new Tween(poster[sliderNum],'x',Strong.easeOut,poster[sliderNum].x,-800,2,true);
    if (sliderNum == sliderMaxNum){
        trace(String(sliderNum));
        trace(String(sliderMaxNum));
        sliderNum = 0;
    } else {
        sliderNum = sliderNum +1;
    }   

    var myTween2:Tween = new Tween(poster[sliderNum],'x',Strong.easeOut,poster[sliderNum].x,(myStage.stageWidth - 640)/2,2,true);
}
```

i use this code to load XML:

```
function loadXML(event:Event):void{

    sliderXML=XML(sliderXMLloader.data);
    var xmlDoc:XMLDocument = new XMLDocument();
    xmlDoc.ignoreWhite = true;
    var menuXML:XML = XML(sliderXMLloader.data);
    xmlDoc.parseXML(menuXML.toXMLString());

    //var X:int = 100;

    for each(var listItem:XML in sliderXML..listItem){

             strTitle[sliderMaxNum] = listItem.itemTitle.toString();
             strPosterLink[sliderMaxNum] = listItem.posterLink.toString();
             strVideoLink[sliderMaxNum] = listItem.videoLink.toString();

             var _temp:Loader = new Loader();
             poster.splice(sliderMaxNum, 0, _temp);
             poster[sliderMaxNum].load(new URLRequest(strPosterLink[sliderMaxNum]));
             //var posterClip:MovieClip = new MovieClip();  //load the movieclip
             //posterClip.addChild(poster[sliderMaxNum]);  //convert poster[sliderMaxNum] to movieClip
             addChild(poster[sliderMaxNum]);
             poster[sliderMaxNum].x = myStage.stageWidth;
             poster[sliderMaxNum].y = 28;

             poster[sliderMaxNum].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, poster_click(sliderMaxNum));

             sliderMaxNum = sliderMaxNum+1;
             }
    LastSliderNum = sliderMaxNum - 1;
    //*************************************************
    var myTween:Tween = new Tween(poster[sliderNum],'x',Strong.easeOut,poster[sliderNum].x,(myStage.stageWidth - 640)/2,2,true);
    //*************************************************
}
```

Comment: i  just minimized it and left only the code where i think could be a problem

Comment: I don't see 'poster' declared or defined anywhere - I assume it is. It's referenced in both sets of code, and would definitely throw an error if it was not... This error generally comes up if you are referencing a variable that hasn't been defined or declared yet. You should debug the app to find the exact line number where the error is coming up. I don't see anything glaring...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is a full code:

```
import flash.display.Stage;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.xml.XMLDocument;
import flash.text.TextField;
//tween - start
import fl.transitions.Tween;
import fl.transitions.easing.*;
import fl.transitions.TweenEvent;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

//tween - end

    var myStage:Stage = this.stage;
    myStage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;
    myStage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT;

    var sliderXML:XML = new XML();
    var sliderXMLurl:String = 'sliderXML.xml';
    var sliderXMLreq:URLRequest = new URLRequest(sliderXMLurl);
    var sliderXMLloader:URLLoader = new URLLoader(sliderXMLreq);
    sliderXMLloader.addEventListener("complete",loadXML);

    var sliderNum:int = 0;
    var sliderMaxNum:int = 0;
    var LastSliderNum:int = 0;
    var strTitle:Array = [];
    var strPosterLink:Array = [];
    var strVideoLink:Array = [];
    var poster:Array = [];

    var Playing:int = 1;


addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, fl_EnterFrameHandler);
myStage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, ResizeHandler);

function fl_EnterFrameHandler(event:Event):void
{
    var swfWidth:int = myStage.stageWidth;
    var swfHeight:int = myStage.stageHeight;
    slider_bg.width = swfWidth;
    slider_bg.height = swfHeight;
    slider_header.width = swfWidth;
    slider_bg.height = myStage.stageHeight - slider_header.height - slider_footer.height;
    slider_footer.width = swfWidth;
    slider_footer.y = slider_header.height + slider_bg.height;

    back_btn.x = myStage.stageWidth / 2 - 25 - 65;
    back_btn.y = myStage.stageHeight - 66;
    next_btn.x = myStage.stageWidth / 2 + 30;
    next_btn.y = myStage.stageHeight - 66;
    if (Playing == 0){
        play_btn.x = (myStage.stageWidth - 50) / 2;
        play_btn.y = (myStage.stageHeight - 50 - 31);
        pause_btn.x = play_btn.x;
        pause_btn.y = myStage.stageHeight + 100;
    } else if (Playing == 1) {
        pause_btn.x = (myStage.stageWidth - 50) / 2;
        pause_btn.y = (myStage.stageHeight - 50 - 31);
        play_btn.x = pause_btn.x;
        play_btn.y = myStage.stageHeight + 100;
    }
}

function loadXML(event:Event):void{

    sliderXML=XML(sliderXMLloader.data);
    var xmlDoc:XMLDocument = new XMLDocument();
    xmlDoc.ignoreWhite = true;
    var menuXML:XML = XML(sliderXMLloader.data);
    xmlDoc.parseXML(menuXML.toXMLString());

    //var X:int = 100;

    for each(var listItem:XML in sliderXML..listItem){

             strTitle[sliderMaxNum] = listItem.itemTitle.toString();
             strPosterLink[sliderMaxNum] = listItem.posterLink.toString();
             strVideoLink[sliderMaxNum] = listItem.videoLink.toString();

             var _temp:Loader = new Loader();
             poster.splice(sliderMaxNum, 0, _temp);
             poster[sliderMaxNum].load(new URLRequest(strPosterLink[sliderMaxNum]));
             //var posterClip:MovieClip = new MovieClip();  //load the movieclip
             //posterClip.addChild(poster[sliderMaxNum]);  //convert poster[sliderMaxNum] to movieClip
             addChild(poster[sliderMaxNum]);
             poster[sliderMaxNum].x = myStage.stageWidth;
             poster[sliderMaxNum].y = 28;

             poster[sliderMaxNum].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, poster_click(sliderMaxNum));

             sliderMaxNum = sliderMaxNum+1;
             }
    LastSliderNum = sliderMaxNum - 1;
    //*************************************************
    var myTween:Tween = new Tween(poster[sliderNum],'x',Strong.easeOut,poster[sliderNum].x,(myStage.stageWidth - 640)/2,2,true);
    //*************************************************
}

function ResizeHandler(event:Event):void{
    var i:int = 0;
    for (i=0; i < poster.length; i++) {
        poster[i].x = myStage.stageWidth + 100;
    }
    poster[sliderNum].x = (myStage.stageWidth - 640)/2;
}

function poster_click(i:int):Function{
    var foo:Function = function (evt:MouseEvent):void {
        trace(String(i));
    }

    return foo;
}

function poster_next(i:int):void{

}

//play button*********************************************
play_btn.buttonMode = true;
play_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, playOver);
play_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, playOut);
play_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playClick);

function playOver(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    event.currentTarget.gotoAndPlay('playOver');
}

function playOut(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    event.currentTarget.gotoAndPlay('playOut');
}

function playClick(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    Playing = 1;
}
//pause button*********************************************
pause_btn.buttonMode = true;
pause_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, pauseOver);
pause_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, pauseOut);
pause_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, pauseClick);

function pauseOver(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    event.currentTarget.gotoAndPlay('pauseOver');
}

function pauseOut(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    event.currentTarget.gotoAndPlay('pauseOut');
}

function pauseClick(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    Playing = 0;
}
//back_btn **************************************************
back_btn.buttonMode = true;
back_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, backOver);
back_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, backOut);
back_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, backClick);

function backOver(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    event.currentTarget.gotoAndPlay('backOver');
}

function backOut(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    event.currentTarget.gotoAndPlay('backOut');
}

function backClick(event:MouseEvent):void
{

}
//next_btn ***************************************************
next_btn.buttonMode =true;
next_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, nextOver);
next_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OUT, nextOut);
next_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, nextClick);

function nextOver(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    event.currentTarget.gotoAndPlay('nextOver');
}

function nextOut(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    event.currentTarget.gotoAndPlay('nextOut');
}

function nextClick(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    if (sliderNum > sliderMaxNum){
        sliderNum = 0;
    }
    var myTween:Tween = new Tween(poster[sliderNum],'x',Strong.easeOut,poster[sliderNum].x,-800,2,true);
    if (sliderNum == sliderMaxNum){
        trace(String(sliderNum));
        trace(String(sliderMaxNum));
        sliderNum = 0;
    } else {
        sliderNum = sliderNum +1;
    }   
    poster[sliderNum].x = myStage.stageWidth;
    var myTween2:Tween = new Tween(poster[sliderNum],'x',Strong.easeOut,poster[sliderNum].x,(myStage.stageWidth - 640)/2,2,true);
}
```

i just minimized it and left only the code where i think could be a problem

Comment: Like i say above - debugging this will tell you the exact line, and you can follow the error back from there. I don't see anything alarming sticking out...

Comment: can you tell me how to debug? i am  totaly noob in as3 i am vb/delphi lover

Comment: i did it, i just changed SliderMaxNum int variabale to sliderMaxNum -1 so it works now. thank you for reply, but i realy want to know how to debug

Comment: Nice. Glad you figured it out...  Yeah - debugging is pretty essential. And, generally easy. If you're in the Flash IDE, you just press cntrl+shift+enter and it will launch a debugging session. Any errors will be pointed to by line number and the stack of methods that landed there. Also - you get introspection on all objects currently in scope, and all parameters / values associated with those objects. Its importance cannot be overstated. Good luck!